# Django i18n Javascript Problem

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

I have this problem: When i set a language (it or en)in my django app, [with this form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view), 
the javascript strings are converted always in English.
My base Language is Italian.

This is my configuration:
urls.py:

> js_info_dict = {
>       'domain': 'djangojs',
>       'packages': ('myproject',),
>   }
>
> urlpatterns += patterns('',
>       (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
>   )

I have run this command:

> django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en

To generating the djangojs.mo/po files.
I Have translated the string from it to en in that file.
and i've run:

> django-admin.py compilemessages

Now when I go on the page that contains this JS:

> document.write(gettext('Questa stringa è da tradurre'));

the strings return always 'This string is to be translated', 
(That is the translation of 'Questa stringa è da tradurre')

I have included this js in my html file:

> <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>

Where am i wrong? Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cna you post the example lines from your po file?

Comment: [This](http://dpaste.com/hold/534593/).
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should run

```
django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l en
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

for each language you have :)

Comment: Another tip: Must be added myproject on installed apps! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In your file base.html  add the following lines to the beginning

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
```